# AngularJS, TypeScript, Component Architecture weird behavior

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I've jumped for a while from Angular 6 to Angular JS and I'm trying to code in Component Architecture. The problem is - I'm trying to use `ng-show="somevariable"` to hide / show a div.

**AppRootModule:**

```
export const appRootModule: IModule = module('datawalk', ['asyncFilter'])
  .component('appRoot', new AppRootComponent())
  .component('postModal', new PostModalComponent())
  .service('componentsDataService', ComponentDataService);
```

**PostModalComponent:**

```
export class PostModalComponent {
  public template: string;
  public controller: Injectable<IControllerConstructor>;
  public controllerAs: string;

  constructor() {
    this.controller = PostModalController;
    this.controllerAs = 'postM';
    this.template = PostModalTemplateHtml;
  }
```

**PostModalController**

```
export class PostModalController implements IController {
  public modalVisible: boolean;
 /../

  constructor(componentsDataService: ComponentDataService) {
    /../
    this.modalVisible = false;
    /../
    this.$cds.getModalData().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.showMod === true) {
        this.modalOpen(data);
      }
    });
  }

  public $onInit = async (): Promise<void> => {};

  public modalOpen(post: any): void {
    console.error(this.modalVisible); // false
    this.modalVisible = true;
    console.error(this.modalVisible); // true
    /../ 
  }
```

And the template:

```
<div class="modal" ng-show="modalVisible">
    <div class="modal-body">
        /../
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?
console logs shows that the variable changes, but nothing happen, modal div is still hidden.

Comment: The `$onInit` function looks sketchy. How is `$cds` bound to the `this` object? The `ng-show` should be `ng-show="postM.modalVisible"`. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: I've skipped the line with `this.$cds = componentsDataService`. That's not a problem. I don't have communication from a controller to a template, and don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I've figured it out.

That's not a problem of code, but the problem is inside my IDE.

WebStorm has an issue - it does not recognize a `controllerAs` property in HTML templates of AngularJS in component architecture.

Also tslint works faulty.

I don't recommend to use that with AngularJS with component architecture.

Vs Code works perfect with that.

Comment: There is no need to specify `controllerAs`. If it is omited, the component will default to using `$ctrl`.